# How to merge multiline info property from Active Directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to create CSV file (one line per AD account) with account's Samaccountname and Info from MS AD and then load data from CSV file into SQL table.
Many accounts have multiline Info property in AD, like the following:
PS SQLSERVER:> $InfoCheckInfo
####00123

```
Task9009- no valid feed - 9/10/14
Disabled due to feed 9-12-2014

Feed updated, 9-15-2014

PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

Multiline Info property can include empty lines.

My solution:
Step1.
$Result= $(Get-ADUser $adUserCheck -Properties * | select SamAccountName)
$Result= aaa123

Step2.
I replaced empty lines and merge data:
PS SQLSERVER:> $InfoCheckInfo = $(Get-ADUser $adUserCheck -Properties info | Select-Object  -
ExpandProperty info) -replace "`n", ";"

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> $InfoCheckInfo
####00123;;;Task9009- no valid feed - 9/10/14;Disabled due to feed 9-12-2014;;Feed updated, 9-15-2014
```

Step3.
$Result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName info $InfoCheckInfo
Step4.
$Result | export-csv -Delimiter '~' "D:\test\ad_user_info.csv"  -notype

The problem is that if Info had multiline property, CSV file creates four lines of data, like this:

```
aaa123 ####00123;;;
Task9009- no valid feed - 9/10/14;
Disabled due to feed 9-12-2014;;
Feed updated, 9-15-2014
```

I need one line for each account-
aaa123 ####00123;;;Task9009- no valid feed - 9/10/14;Disabled due to feed 9-12-2014;;Feed updated, 9-15-2014

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would filter out all user objects 1st that will need to be exported and then built PowerShell object in 1 line.
You can rewrite same with in long form with Foreach loop

Another note, I have done a quick test with multiple lines in StreetAddress and the newline character used was

```
`r`n
```

so you should use it in your replace.

This worked for me (use appropriate filter for your use case)

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties info | 
select SamAccountName, @{N="CheckInfo"; E={$_.Info.replace("`r`n", ";")}} | 
export-csv D:\test\ad_user_info.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '~'
```

Comment: Thanks much! Works great, exactly what I need!

Comment: No worries :) don't forget about "What should I do when someone answers my question?
" 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers